# phpmailer multiple recipients error code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, phpmailer

i've been trying to send emails to multiple recipients, and this is my code so far. emails work but only for the one i set manually, not through the form (add email)

can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
<table>
               <fieldset id="" width= "600" class="w3-main"> <b>registratie bij afwijking</b></fieldset>
               <tr><td width="100"><b>Controleur:</b></td><td><input type = "text" name="controleur" class="w3-card-2 w3-row" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" readonly></td></tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>onderwerp</td><td><input type= "text" name="onderwerp"></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>betreft/object</td><td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" onclick="emailNext();">nog een ontvanger.</button>
                    <div id="addEmail"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="emails" value="email verzenden"></td>
                </tr
               </table>
   </form>
  <script>
function emailNext() {
var nextEmail, inside_where;
nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
nextEmail.type = 'text';
nextEmail.name = 'emails[]';
nextEmail.className = 'class_for_styling';
nextEmail.style.display = 'block';
nextEmail.placeholder  = 'Enter E-mail Here';
inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
return false;
}   
</script>              
<?php
if(isset($_POST['emails'])) {
foreach ($_POST[emails] AS $postEmail){
    if ($postEmail){$mail->AddAddress($postEmail);}
}
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$controle = $_POST['controleur'];
$subj = $_POST['onderwerp'];

require 'phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "******";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "TSL";
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->setFrom('*****', ($controle));
$mail->addAddress('****', 'Test mail');
$mail->Subject = ($subj);
$mail->Body = ($msg);

if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }     else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
 }
```

Comment: Opening form is not really important, some questions.. but what i would like to achieve is that the ones who fill out the form click on Addreceiver, and fill in the receivers themself.. therefore foreach mail->addAdress?

Comment: As well as the wrong order problem, `$mail->SMTPSecure = "TSL";` is wrong; should be `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`, and why are going to the effort of turning off auto TLS and then enabling it manually? You would achieve the same result by simply not setting anything! Bear in mind that a form which allows you to specify a to address and something that is (or is included in) a message body is also known as a spam gateway, and is a very bad thing. Validate all the things; use whitelists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... although it is not specified in their documentation, I'm pretty sure you can use multiple emails comma-separated using one call `$mail->AddAddress()`.

So you can just do `$mail->AddAddress(implode(', ', $_POST['emails']));`

Of course, this must be done **after** the line `$mail = new PHPMailer;`

Comment: is it possible for the placeholder to be a sorta select option between email adresses?

Comment: I've no idea why this was selected as the correct answer; It's just wrong and won't work, which is why it's not mentioned in the docs! `addAddress()` does not accept arrays or comma-delimited strings. If in doubt, [read the code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L811).

Comment: @Synchro It has worked for me on all my projects, so...? And I am assuming it has worked for the OP. Where exactly does it say in the code that it does not accept comma-delimited strings?! Just because it doesn't say doesn't mean it cannot be done.

Comment: No it hasn't. I think you misunderstand the function of documentation. If it tried to cover every possible thing that something *doesn't* do, we'd be here all day. If you want confirmation, just read the code I linked to, which you will see does absolutely nothing to even attempt to support multiple addresses in a single call. You are of course free to override it and add that functionality yourself, but it is **not** there by default.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are **overwriting** the array after adding the addresses.

**Start with:**

```
require 'phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

End then add the addresses.